# Doctrine 2.2/Symfony 2.2: Persisting an entity with a composite foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I must first establish that I'm a total newcomer to Doctrine, even though I know enough about SQL and PHP/Symfony 2.

So, I created this IssueType entity associated to a SQL table:

```
/**
 * IssueType
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Blog\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\IssueTypeRepository")
 */
class IssueType
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    // Getters, setters...
}
```

I populated it, so the content of said table is now:

```
id | name
1  | Bande dessinée
2  | Livre
3  | Film
4  | Disque
```

Now I have this other entity, Role, which uses a composite key, made up of a regular string (name) and a foreign key (id from IssueType):

```
/**
 * Role
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Blog\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\RoleRepository")
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @var IssueType
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Blog\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\IssueType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $issueType;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $name;

    // Getters, setters...
}
```

Both tables are correctly generated by doctrine in the database. However, although it should be trivial, I can't for the life of me find a single example of a correct and successful persist operation in such a case.

What I try to do is the following:

```
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $issueType = new IssueType();
    $issueType->setId(1);

    $role = new Role();
    $role->setIssueType($issueType);
    $role->setName('Dessinateur');

    $manager->persist($role);
    $manager->flush();
```

I thus try to persist the following:

```
Role: {
    IssueType: {id: 1, name: ''},
    name: 'Dessinateur',
}
```

And what I get is this nasty exception:

```
Entity of type Blog\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Role has identity through a foreign entity Blog\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\IssueType, however this entity has no identity itself. You have to call EntityManager#persist() on the related entity and make sure that an identifier was generated before trying to persist 'Blog\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Role'. In case of Post Insert ID Generation (such as MySQL Auto-Increment or PostgreSQL SERIAL) this means you have to call EntityManager#flush() between both persist operations.
```

I understand it wants me to persist first the foreign entity, but I don't want to do that, since the foreign issue type of ID#1 already exists in the database and thus don't need persisting. How can it ask me that when I did not specify any 'cascade' attribute in the annotations?

BTY I tried anyway to do as it says, and it expectedly ended up with a duplicate entry error.

So, what should I do to make Doctrine understand that the foreign issue type should not be persisted?

**EDIT**

artmees came up with the following solution, which works fine:

```
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$issueType = $manager->getRepository('BlogCoreBundle:IssueType')->find(1);

$role = new Role();
$role->setIssueType($issueType);
$role->setName('Dessinateur');

$manager->persist($role);
$manager->flush();
```

However this implies making an additional request to the database which could have been avoided if not using Doctrine. Since I already know the foreign Id to use, is there any way to use it directly with the persist(), without going to such lengths as actually retrieving the full object from the database?

Comment: As far as I know (to qualify any possible bull).. When you call `->find(1)` it lazy loads the object rather than loading it entirely. When you then pass it to the `Role()` object it gets what it needs to from the proxy version of the object, in this respect it would be the id (rather than the whole object).
After you have created your object you need to call persist (to queue the object to be database'd) and then flush to push the queue to the database. Using it the proper way ensures you are connecting the right objects rather than fresh objects with random, possibly incorrect, id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$issueType = $manager->find('IssueTypeRepository', 1);

$role = new Role();
$role->setIssueType($issueType);
$role->setName('Dessinateur');

$manager->persist($role);
$manager->flush();
```

Comment: Already tried, as I say at the end of my description. Leads to a dusplicate error. Anyway, I don't want to persist the issue type, as it already exists in the database.

What I can't do here is define the (already persisted) foreign key of issue_type that my new $role entry should use.

Comment: i updated the code try it and see if it works ?
since the `$issueType` already exists try getting it [check the documentation here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#querying)

Comment: It works, thanks! But I have a feeling that it is not the optimal solution ; this is an additional SQL request to the database that I would have avoided if not using Doctrine. I suspect thus that there is an even better way to do this.

Comment: I apparently don't have enough 'reputation' to do that, sorry. Actually it's my first post here.

Comment: I read it all and that's not what it says. It says everyone can create/answer questions, but nothing about voting up or down. If you talk about setting your answer as my accepted answer, I prefer to wait for other answers before. I tell you that the site just won't let me vote, it really can't be helped. So let's drop it for now and stop flooding the answers with this foolish debate.

Comment: according to this [article](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork.html) in the doctrine documentation, my guess is that doctrine will issue only the UPDATE/INSERT statement to the database and exclude the SELECT statement.

Comment: use $manager->getReference(...) to avoid the useless extra query.

Comment: sorry i don't know where to put the `$manager->getReference(...)` and what will i replace the `...` with ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old article, but...

Just to add to artmees answer, if you know the ID and you just want to insert that, you don't need to load the entity, simply use a reference.

```
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$issueType = $manager->getReference('BlogCoreBundle:IssueType',1);

$role = new Role();
$role->setIssueType($issueType);
$role->setName('Dessinateur');

$manager->persist($role);
$manager->flush();
```

That will create a proxy with that ID (1), which is all you need in order to save the role entity.